# specialFolderPath("Users/myname") is not working - Livecode

Tags: livecode

I'm download file from url and I want to put file to Home directory(Users/myname/livecode).

This my code :

```
      set the itemDel to slash
      put last item of pURL into tFilename
      put specialFolderPath("Users/myname") & slash before tFileName
      put URL pURL into URL ("binfile:" & tFileName)
```

My platform is MAC OS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if 'Users' works as an identifier.  If it does, you can try;

```
put specialFolderPath("Users") & slash & myname & slash before tFileName
```

If it doesn't, the following may work;

```
put specialFolderPath("Home") & slash before tFileName
```

The 'Home' identifier should give the current user's home folder.

Comment: `specialFolderpath("home")` works. Only pre-defined parameters work. You can find a list of these parameters in the LiveCode Dictionary. Besides these parameters, you can use numbers. My book Programming LiveCode for the Real Beginner contains a complete list with all possible values. It is probably much longer than you imagined.

Comment: at http://sonsothunder.com/devres/livecode/tips/file010.htm you find a complete overview of possible values for specialfolderpath

Comment: That link is slightly outdated and doesn't contain all values for MacOS.

Comment: But to get a detailed overview right now it is much faster to visit that page now than waiting for your book to arrive. ;)  Without question your book is a very useful source of information!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question/sample to put the file into a subfolder in the home folder called livecode you could do it this way:

```
set the itemDel to slash
  put last item of pURL into tFilename

  //set the target folder ("~" works on Mac OS X and Linux)
  put "~/livecode" into tTargetFolder

  //check if the folder livecode already exists, if not then create it
  if there is not a folder tTargetFolder then create folder tTargetfolder

  put tTargetfolder and slash before tFileName
  // tFilename now contains the complete path

  put URL pURL into URL ("binfile:" & tFileName)
```

Using "~" instead using specialfolderpath("home") helps to spent some typing. 
But be aware that "~" only works under Mac OS X and Linux.

Comment: I would prefer the solution with "home", because it works on Mac OS X, Linux _and_ Windows.